# Why does my parcel-bundler fail even on the simplest things?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parceljs

So as I say in the title I'm having a simple `index.html` file that has a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.scss">` to import my styles. When I run the `parcel index.html` I get an error that says `.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/builtins/css-loader.js: JSON5: invalid character '}' at 1:23`. 
Here is my css in case you want to take a look at it:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I'm using the parcel-bundler without any configuration and even the first example from the get started page of the Parcel website can't run without throwing out an error about an invalid character.

If I remove the css import then the project builds. `Node` is on version 10.16.3 and `npm` is 6.9.0

I've tried using a lower node version but I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: Why are you on Node 10? The current LTS is v14. Also, slightly more related to your problem, why does your HTML have a link for an `scss` file instead of a `css` file?

Comment: To be fair, JavaScript bundlers are a giant failure. You better serve each module yourself

Answer (score 2):

I have had like your Error but like this :

> invalid Version :
>
> /node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/builtins/css-loader.js: JSON5:
> invalid Version ..

so what I did .. I made uninstall to parcel then I used an older version then It has worked successfully  ..

I have used **parcel@1.12.3** instead of **parcel@1.12.4**

Answer (score 0):

I had a blank .babelrc in my root folder.
Deleted it fixed the problem for me